# Difference of xss clean and global xss filtering

Tags: codeigniter, xss

I am a beginner codeigniter developer and need your help.
I have a form that the is submitted to a function in the controller and I want to apply the form_validation library rules on the post data received from the form.
All I need to know is this:
Does $config['global_xss_filtering'] switch in input class do the same job as  xss_clean rule in form_validation class?

Comment: Do I get the same result if I let the switch turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's same. If you have enabled $config['global_xss_filtering'] through the config file you don't have to call  xss_clean in form validation,

but if you have switched off $config['global_xss_filtering'], you have to call xss_clean in form validation and also you have to add additional parameter (TRUE or FALSE) in input->post function as well in order to do xss filtering. see below.

```
$name = trim($this->input->post('name',TRUE));
```

This will be helpful if you are using WYSIWYG editor in your application, then you have to switch off $config['global_xss_filtering'] and you have to pass additional parameter in input->post function like above, TRUE - for enable filtering and FALSE for disabling (Wherever you use WYSIWYG  editor).

Comment: Although the result is the same, it is worth noting that `global_xss_filtering` modifies the actual `$_POST` array when `CI_Input` is constructed while `$this->input->post('name', TRUE)` does not change the `$_POST` array.  If at any point in time you realize you need a single variable to not have XSS filtering applied, you may have to make some large changes in your code to get it. It is best to have `global_xss_filtering` off and overload `CI_Input::post()` to have `$xss_clean` default to `TRUE` instead of `FALSE`, then always access `$_POST` variables through the `CI_Input::post()` method.

Comment: Although this answer is quite old. Please explain why we have to disable the xss filter for the wysiwyg editor.Same for this case also, why we cant use xss_clean in this case also $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'required|xss_clean'); (wrong) $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'desc', 'required'); (correct)

Comment: because that thing strips the "style" from any html code `$evil_attributes = array('on\w*', 'style', 'xmlns', 'formaction');`